# How to make a single View globally accessible?

Tags: android, view

Is there any way to make a single View (in this case a TextView) globally accessible? I tried putting the TextView in it's own XML-file, like so:

```
<!-- File: list_header.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
</TextView>
```

However, when trying to access this TextView (using `mListHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_header)`) I receive `null`.

I think I've seem some example using this approach, so I think it should be possible. If not, I would be happy to get some help in finding out another approach.

Maybe this question should have been labeled otherwise, since my main question is how to solve a specific problem:

The TextView in question is supposed to be used as a header in a ListView. This header will be used in a number of ListViews, so I want to set it's properties using XML. I could put it in the same XML-file as the ListView's, but I don't want the TextView appear in any other way as header for the ListView's. One way to solve the problem would be to put the TextView in it's own XML-file, as I tried to do, but it didn't work.

Now, I'm not sure about the Stack Overflow practice in situations like this, but in any case, I'd like an answer for both questions.

Comment: In Android Developer's [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) they use something quite similar. That was where I got the idea from. They use a layout consisting of a single TextView (no LinearLayout or anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflate the view and add it as a header in the ListView:

```
  View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
  list.addHeaderView(header);
  BaseAdapter adapter = getAdapter(); 
  list.setAdapter(adapter); //the header view must be added before you set the adapter
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using either an <include /> or <merge /> in your layouts to use a single control definition in multiple layouts. There is a tutorial on includes [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).

Comment: Yes, well, that's good practice, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: The thing I wanted to do, was to use the same TextView as header for each of my ListView's, without putting it in any other XML-file, since I didn't want it to be displayed in any other way. I guess I could have put in the ListView's XML-file and made it invisible, but that would've been messy.
I'm not sure how I should describe it better, but using a LayoutInflater solved my problem.
Thanks for the answer, by the way! :) Shame I can't vote up.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting null because a `View` with the ID you are trying to find is not in the view hierarchy you set with `setContentView`.

You therefore have two options:

1. Use an `<include />` tag to include the layout you want into the larger layouts you set with `setContentView`
2. Use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate the `View` and add it to the existing view hierarchy created in `setContentView`

Making a `View` object itself (not the layout) globally accessible, i.e. by putting it in a `static` field, will cause memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was somewhat enligthening. Shame I can't vote up. 
I understood that the View was outside of scope, but I didn't think about `setContentView` narrowing it down.